# Run tab from android studio bottom toolbar has disappeared

Tags: android, android-studio

There used to be a Run tab in bottom toolbar of Android Studio. But the tab is not showing anymore. How to bring it back? Please check the below image to see where it was before it disappeared.

The Run tab used to be in the red circle before the TODO tab.

[image]

Comment: if you are not running an application it will not appear, when something is running, press alt+4 as mentiond in answer by @ramin eftekhari

Answer (score 47, accepted):

View -> Tool Windows -> Run

Or use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> shortcut key.

Comment: it is right when app is running. otherwise RUN tab is not accessable

Comment: Why do you need RUN tab when app is not running?

Comment: i do not need :) comment is for @saurabh sarpotdar , who actually asked this question.

Comment: What if the View -> Tool Widnws -> Run   is not clickable and alt + 4 wont do anything ?

Comment: same here run not only not clickable, but also not in the menu, and alt 4 does not change anything. 
Why need that? For diagnostics. Logcat insists on setting up sdk, which is up and running, so Run is the place when you can check for errors.

Comment: Solved. Run the process to see the run option in the view / tool windows menu. Really weird it shows only when relevant.

Comment: command + 4 for mac

Answer (score 44):

For the latest version of Android Studio (4.0+) go to:

`View > Appearance > Tool Window Bars`

make sure **`Tool Window Bars`** is checked.

For older versions:

The following shortcut key doesn't work in **Android studio 3.0**:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

For anyone who accidentally hides the bottom toolbar due to some configuration etc go to:

*View > Tool Buttons* **(make sure its checked)**

This worked for me, the accepted answer only reveals the required view not all of them.

Just putting this in case someone stumbles to this question

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me in **Android Studio 4.0**:

*View > Appearance -> Tool Window Bars*

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Android Studio, you can display it again by going to:

`View -> Appearance -> Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

If we closed it then following will work.

View > Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

otherwise **we have to run the build once, then it will automatically shows up.**